# laptop-mode-tools segfault, can't boot

Tags: segmentation-fault

I installed the `laptop-mode-tools` package. When the service starts (term reads "Enabling laptop mode"), a segmentation fault occurs.

I can't boot the system now. I tried to remove the package from recovery mode, but the filesystem is mounted read-only, and selecting an option that would mount it for writing inits `laptop-mode-tools` and segfaults again.

EDIT: I remounted / with `rw`, but running `dpkg` to remove the package **also** causes a segfault.

Nevermind getting the package to work, how can I recover the system?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Answer (score 1):

I entered in recovery mode and delete with rm the `/etc/laptop-mode-tools` folder with its sub-folders.
Then I re-give the command `apt-get purge laptop-mode-tools` and all works!

Answer (score 0):

When you are in recovery mode, remove the package with:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge laptop-mode-tools
```

Comment: As I said, that also causes a segfault. I used a chroot and solved the problem

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn You said that you runned "`dpkg` to remove the package". And it was normal to use root privileges. For this I used `sudo` in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Ubuntu live installation drive to `chroot` into the local system:

```
# mkdir mnt
# mount -t proc proc mnt/proc
# mount -t sysfs sys mnt/sys
# mount -o bind /dev mnt/dev
# chroot mnt /bin/bash
```

Inside the `chroot`, I could `apt-get remove --purge` the package with no issues.

Unfortunately for me, the system never booted again. The kernel panics during startup.